# change data from array state reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state, onchange

**when adding products to cart it can add with quantity.after adding cart i want to change the quantity also from the cart.but it will not change in there anything i need to change in set state.how can i fix this? really appreciate the help**

**cart.jsx**

```
 const Store = () => {
    const [listData, setListData] = useState({ lists: [] });
   

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Token'));
            const body ={token}
            const result = await axios.post(
                'http://localhost:4000/store/cart',body);
            setListData({ lists: result.data });
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);


   
  
  const onChangeProductData = (e) => {
    setListData({
        ...listData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
    
}


    
    
   
 
  const itemsPrice =  listData.lists.reduce((a, c) => a + c.quantity * c.product_price, 0);;
  const totalPrice = itemsPrice;
  
    return (
        <div className="store">
        <div className="header">
          <a href="/store" className="logo">Milk.Lk</a>
          <div className="menu">
            <div className="dropdown">
              <button className="dropbtn">Category</button>
              <div className="dropdown-content">
                <a href="/freshmilk">FreshMilk</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="/login">Contact us</a>
          </div>
          <div className="header-right">
            <a href="/register">SingUp</a>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">    
        <div className="cart">
               
        {listData.lists.length === 0 && <div>Cart is empty</div>}
                    {listData.lists.map((current, i) => (
                      
                       <div className='product-cart container'>
        
        
                         <div className="colm1" ><img key={i} className='product-cart-img' src={`http://localhost:4000/uploads/${current.image}`} alt='' /></div>
        
        <div className="colm2" ><a >{current.product_name}</a></div>
        <div className="colm3"><div class="form-group mx-sm-4 mb-2">

<select class="form-control " name="quantity" onChange={onChangeProductData} value={current.quantity} >
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

{current.product_price}
          Remove 
          
                        ))}
                    
                
                
              
                **Total Price**
              
              
              
                **${totalPrice}**

```
        </div>
        </div>
        
    );
                      
}

export default Store;
```

Comment: why list array is inside an object, it can have other properties as well?

Comment: ya.currently i'm new to react.is there anything to change?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update a quantity for a particular product but you're updating listData object, to fix this

First you need to pass some identifier to onChangeProductData if there is id on each product you can pass that or pass index

```
<select class="form-control " name="quantity" onChange={(ev) => onChangeProductData(ev, i)} value={current.quantity} > // here you can pass some id as well instead of index
```

Now

```
const onChangeProductData = (e, i) => {
    const list = [...listData];
    list[i] = {
        ...list[i],
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
    setListData({
        ...listData,
        list
    })    
}
```

Above changes will fix your problem:

Suggestion:
listData sould be like -

```
const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);
```

Comment: if this worked, please accept the answer.

Comment: thanks for the valuable answer and suggestion.